# Does AWS EC2 allows for a process of scheduled instance start -> run scheduled code -> instance close repeatedly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have some code I have to manually run daily. I would like to automate this and felt EC2 would be the best option.

What I'm not clear on is whether or not I can do this while I am away without having the Remote Desktop up.

Namely, if I'm away from my host machine for multiple days, would AWS allow for the following implementation?:

1. Instance starts on a schedule
2. Within the instance a set of code is run based on a schedule
3. Instance stops on a schedule

I know I can start and stop instances on a schedule as I've done that. What I don't know is if, within those automatically started instances, I can have code automatically run.

Thanks in advance and please let me know if you need any additional info.

Comment: Yes, you can use [cloud-init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html) to run a user script on an instance start.

Comment: Short description. By default, user data scripts and cloud-init directives run only during the first boot cycle when an EC2 instance is launched.

Comment: You can write a shell script that will trigger the code and you can add this Shell Script under `crontab`. Example : https://phoenixnap.com/kb/crontab-reboot